# Scan and save the images on server using dynamic web twain

Tags: java, twain, scanning

i am using dynaimc web twain to scan images.

```
    function scan() {
    ......
    .....
    dynamicWebTwain1.AcquireImage();
                 dynamicWebTwain1.attachEvent('OnPostAllTransfers',dynamicWebTwain1_OnPostAllTransfers);
                 zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$btnScan'), 'onScan', null, {toServer:true}));
    }

    function dynamicWebTwain1_OnPostAllTransfers(){
    ........
    ...........
    strActionPage += "&AttachmentCode="+attachmentCode+"&AttachmentDesc="+attachmentDesc+"&AttachmentDetail="+attachmentDetail+"&FileType="+fileType+"&FileName="+fileName;
    dynamicWebTwain1.HTTPUploadAllThroughPostAsPDF(document.location.hostname, strActionPage, fileName);
    }
```

problem is before completion of `dynamicWebTwain1_OnPostAllTransfers(){ }` method      `zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$btnScan'), 'onScan', null, {toServer:true}));` is beign called which is creating an issue for me..is there any way by which i can hold the execution of `zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$btnScan'), 'onScan', null, {toServer:true}));` untill `dynamicWebTwain1_OnPostAllTransfers(){` completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Rachel from Dynamsoft. Thanks for using our Dynamic Web TWAIN SDK.

You can update the code like below and try again to see how it works.

```
  function scan() {
......
.....
dynamicWebTwain1.AcquireImage(); //this method is non-blocking
             dynamicWebTwain1.attachEvent('OnPostAllTransfers',dynamicWebTwain1_OnPostAllTransfers);

}
function dynamicWebTwain1_OnPostAllTransfers(){
........
...........
strActionPage += "&AttachmentCode="+attachmentCode+"&AttachmentDesc="+attachmentDesc+"&AttachmentDetail="+attachmentDetail+"&FileType="+fileType+"&FileName="+fileName;
dynamicWebTwain1.HTTPUploadAllThroughPostAsPDF(document.location.hostname, strActionPage, fileName);
zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$btnScan'), 'onScan', null, {toServer:true}));
}
```